# Python xlsxwriter filtering by columns and posting to another worksheet

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I think I am going beyond the realms of my amateur Python knowledge.  I am using xlsxwriter to filter a txt file and grab data surrounding a specific string match.  The captured data I place into an Excel table related to 4 columns of TIMESTAMP, STRING_MATCH_VALUE, VALUE1, VALUE2 (like the table below) I am ok up to here.

[image: Output table]

My next task is to try and filter the Excel worksheet by VALUE1 column.  This is where my Python knowledge is being stretched.  I am looking to filter for ranges between -88.00 and -88.99 and -89.00 and -89.99 and then post the filtered data to specific worksheets in the Excel.  I looked at xlsxwriter filtering and have produced some code below after reading the xlsxwriter documents, but I think I am struggling with the correct wording.  Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
worksheetFILTER.autofilter(0, 0, FILTERtot, 3)
worksheetFILTER.filter_column(2, 'x > -89 and x < -88')

# Hide rows here if they don't match
rowfilt = 1
for row_data in (worksheetFILTER):
    value1 = row_data[2]

    # does it match?
    if value1 == (r'88.\d{2}'):
        # yes.
        pass
    else:
        # No - hide rows.
        worksheetFILTER.set_row(rowfilt, options={'hidden': True})

    # Place matched rows to different worksheet
    worksheetFILTERED.write_row(rowfilt, 0, row_data)

    # Move to next row.
    rowfilt += 1
```

Comment: why don't you filter when you are getting the data from the text file?

Comment: Hi Padraic - Yeah, your right, that would make the best sense - apologies for the stupid question - It was good to get a second opinion though.  Thanks

Comment: Don't worry it is not  a stupid question. I am sure there is a way to do what you want but I imagine it is easier just to filter initially.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```
# Does it match our criteria.
if value1 > -89 and value1 < -88
    # Yes. Then don't filter this row.
    pass
else:
    # No. Then hide the row.
    worksheetFILTER.set_row(rowfilt, options={'hidden': True})
```

Basically the condition should match the autofilter condition you set up earlier:

```
worksheetFILTER.filter_column(2, 'x > -89 and x < -88')
```

For more details see the [Working with Autofilters](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_autofilters.html#working-with-autofilters) section of the docs and the autofilter sub-examples in [autofilter.py](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_autofilter.html).